# Want to have one class with QTableView and QAbstractTableModel

Tags: qt

I keep all cached database data in memory inside similar containers.

```
//data struct
struct rs{
    uint f_i;//index
    byte f_er;//errors count
    QString f_name;//function name
    ....
};
//data
std::vector< rs * > r;
```

To do quick sorting just swapping pointers inside vector.
And to keep more free memory and for some speed issues.
Working good.

Each time I need derive a new class from QAbstractTableModel and change structures and methods. And connect signals and slots with a new derived from QTableView class.
It's so hard for me to maintain connections between multiple objects.
I want just to have all in one, and simply call a method I need.

So, I know that "Multiple inheritance from QObject is not supported by Qt".
But want to find a way to do one single class.
Any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: you class does not has to be "a QTableView an also a QAbstractTableModel", it could be "a QTableView that has a QAbstractTableModel" or "something that has a QTableView and a QAbstractTableModel".

Comment: Of course. But I will need again to connect signals and slots, etc. For example, I've got "return" key on QTableView object. I need to test if flags for currentIndex() has Qt::ItemIsEditable. And after that I will edit or not. And so many such situations. Another example, I need to draw a pointer on currently selected row. I need to connect again to send currentIndex() to QAbstractTableModel to know where to draw it inside data().